# What chip is this?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I'm trying to repair a broken laptop screen and noticed this chip is getting extremely hot. I desoldered it, but I can't find a replacement for it - there is only the following marking on it:
`CW=EE` `F15`

Here's a photo:

[image: chip]

I found an old listing on Aliexpress for a similar chip, but there is no information as for what this chip is:

https://www.aliexpress.com/i/4000270985731.html

There were some large inductors and capacitors around it on the board so I assume it's some kind of power chip.

The screen in question is an `N156BGE-LB1`: https://www.touchandscreen.de/mediafiles/Datasheets/INNOLUX/N156BGE-LB1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a DC-DC converter.

Comment: Most likely. I just don't know what the manufacturer / part number of this is, an I'm looking for a replacement.

Comment: If at least you could find the datasheet, you may find a compatible component, but it is difficult to find the datasheet.

Comment: Most probably a PMIC, like this other component from Mouser https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/NXP-Semiconductors/MC32PF1510A1EP?qs=MLItCLRbWswHzkDPfGBljQ%3D%3D

Comment: To be clear - I'm looking for the exact same chip, or an equivalent one for replacement. I tried searching for power chips with the same package and couldn't find anything - I was hoping someone would be able to identify it.